# Count function and grouping function in SQL based on two columns from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have a music store database with 4 tables which are

1. Invoice
2. Track
3. Invoice Line
4. Genre

I want to get the most popular genre for each country. the results must show the country name, genre-wise total purchases, and genre name. I have created a parent-child relationship between 4 tables to get genre name against each Invoice line
The code i am trying is

```
SELECT Invoice.BillingCountry, Genre.Name, Genre.GenreId
FROM Invoice, InvoiceLine, Track, Genre
WHERE Invoice.InvoiceId = InvoiceLine.InvoiceId AND InvoiceLine.TrackId = Track.TrackId AND 
Track.GenreId = Genre.GenreId
ORDER by Invoice.BillingCountry
```

results I am getting

[image: current coding result]

now I want to get country-wise, genre-wise purchases.

Can anybody please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `GROUP BY` and `count` to achieve it, something like this:

```
SELECT Invoice.BillingCountry, Genre.Name, count(*) as purchase_count
FROM Invoice, InvoiceLine, Track, Genre 
WHERE Invoice.InvoiceId = InvoiceLine.InvoiceId 
      AND InvoiceLine.TrackId = Track.TrackId 
      AND Track.GenreId = Genre.GenreId 
GROUP BY Invoice.BillingCountry, Genre.Name
ORDER BY Invoice.BillingCountry, Genre.Name
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. now the problem is, i only need to show the entries with the maximum count invoice.billingcountry wise. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You can query the results of the query using GROUP BY and MAX on the needed column, instead of count. Also, if my previous answered your initial question, please mark it as correct.

Comment: yes, your previous answer was quite correct. but the thing is I am unable to process subqueries. Should I run your previous answered query as a subquery and the same query as the main query but this time instead of using max, instead of count function.